# Different precision in math.sin and math.cos

Tags: python, math, trigonometry

I have a simple question for the computation of a sin and cos of a radiant in python.

It seems to me, that the sin is limited to values bigger than "x.xe-8" while cos is capable to compute much smaller values, like "x.xe-90" in my example.

Is there a way (except round before the sin) to get the sin to work properly (within its precision limits of course).

```
>>> import math
>>> math.sin(1.0e-8)
1e-08
>>> math.sin(1.0e-9)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: math domain error
>>> math.cos(1.0e-90)
1.0
```

Edit: The problem was the OS. There is an update available. (https://www.suse.com/support/update/announcement/2012/suse-ru-20120681-1.html)

Comment: What python are you using? This seems really weird.

Comment: Works fine for me down to `math.sin(1e-90)` on 2.7.1

Comment: You could define `real_sin(x) = sin(x) if abs(x) > 1e-8 else x`, but there seems to be something wrong with your environment.

Comment: Hi, I use python 2.6.8. Hm, I guess it is time to upgrade then. Thank you both for the fast answers.

Comment: Nope, I got the same errors in math.sin for values smaller than 1.0e-8 in python 2.7.5.

Comment: Works fine for me with 2.7.3 from the Python website. How are you installing Python (the standard binary? from source? another distribution?). Is it CPython or another variant? Which OS are you using?

Comment: Ok, now it is going to be weird. Because you guys said you can compute it, I tried it on a different computer and it worked. Any ideas? Like I have written above the new installation of 2.7.5 hasn't solved it.

Comment: Works for me with Python 2.6.6. 32-bit vs. 64-bit, perhaps? My system is 64-bit.

Comment: It might have something to do with how is your interpreted compiled.

Comment: I downloaded the 2.7.5 compressed source tarball version from the python.org website. Then "./configure --prefix=/path/to/install" and then "make" and "make install"

Comment: Is there something I have to ./configure differently for 64bit? I have a 64bit machine here. My OS is SUSE 11.2. Interpreter is GCC 4.3.4.

Comment: Update: It seems to be the OS version. On machines with SUSE 11.1 installed there is no problem.

Comment: Quite strange. The only floating point value that gives that error seems to be `inf`s(on my machine). It's probably something related to the `libm` version(since the `math` module should simply be a wrapper for C's standard mathematical functions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was the OS. There is an update for Suse Enterprise 11.2 available.
--> https://www.suse.com/support/update/announcement/2012/suse-ru-20120681-1.html

Answer (score 0):

But `sin(x) ~ x` around the origin so why are you so worried by this?  Subtracting `x**3/6.0` must get you close enough for most calcs (if not, adding x**5/120.0 must).

Comment: I does not care about the error, I care about the abortion of the script. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I had a look at the code (Python 2.7.5). You can find the relevant lines in `Modules/mathmodule.c`:

```
r = (*func)(x);
PyFPE_END_PROTECT(r);
if (Py_IS_NAN(r)) {
    if (!Py_IS_NAN(x))
        errno = EDOM;
    else
        errno = 0;
}
else if (Py_IS_INFINITY(r)) {
    if (Py_IS_FINITE(x))
        errno = can_overflow ? ERANGE : EDOM;
    else
        errno = 0;
}
```

`func` is a pointer to the system `sin` function, and `can_overflow` is 0. So your system’s `sin` either returns `NaN`  or infinity for the given input.

Comment: Thank you. There is an OS update available, which solves the bug. Is it possible to mark this thread as solved?

Comment: There is a checkmark next to each answer. You can select the answer that solved your problem by clicking on that checkmark next to it. If none of the given answers are acceptable, you can write an answer yourself and accept it. Apart from that you should upvote (click on the litte up arrow next to it) every answer that was helpful to you.